# Solving triple summation in context of nested loops

Tags: summation, algorithms

I'm trying to follow along with class notes that solves a triple summation for an algorithm for finding the maximum sum in a subinterval, with an array of length 14 (with 2 nested loops, 3 total loops) that begins like this:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i}^n \sum_{k=i}^j 1$$

Intuitively, I would think that this the function from this algorithm, say $f$ $\in O(n^3)$ since we have 3 nested loops and we seem to be running each loop close to $n$ times for each element in the array.

Would really appreciate any help, feeling quite stuck here and not sure how to properly interpret a problem like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Direct Approach**

So we are looking at $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n (j - i + 1)$. If you think of the entries with indices $(i,j)$ as an $n \times n$, matrix, our summation uses the upper triangle of the matrix (where $j >i$) and the main diagonal (where $j=i$).

Note that along the diagonal, $j=i$ and so $i-j=0$ and the summand is all $1$, and there are exactly $n$ entries in the diagonal.

In the next diagonal band, there are $n-1$ entries, but there, $i = j+1$ so $i-j=1$ and the summand is $2$.

It's not hard to see the pattern, with each diagonal band having $i-j=d$ with $n-d$ elements, and the summand of $d+1$, resulting in the total sum of $(n-d)(d+1)$ for each such band.

**Exact Approach**

Here one alternative is to sum the result directly by changing the index in the inside summation to $k=j-i+1$. Then, since $i \le j \le n$, we have $1 \le j-i+1 = k \le n - i+1$ and the inner sum converts. A similar trick can be used on the outer sum letting $m = n-i+1$:

$$
\begin{split}
S &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=i}^n (j - i + 1) \quad \text{substitute } k = j-i+1\\
  &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^{n-i+1} k \\
  &= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(n-i+1)(n-i+2)}{2} \quad \text{substitute } m = n-i+1\\
  &= \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{m(m+1)}{2} \\
  &= \Theta\left(n^3\right)
\end{split}
$$

---

**Direct Approach**

So now we deal with $\sum_{d=0}^n (d+1)(n-d)$. Note that when $d \approx n/2$ we get quadratic terms in the sum since $(d+1) \approx n/2 \approx n - d$ and the term becomes roughly $(n/2)^2 = n^2/4$.

Thus, we have a linear number of terms which are at most quadratic, hence the sum is really $O\left(n^3\right)$.

**Exact Approach**

Here we can also sum directly to get a lower bound with an upper bound. Note that
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{d=0}^n (d+1)(n-d)
 &= \sum_{d=0}^n \left[n + (n-1)d - d^2\right]\\
 &= n \sum_{d=0}^n 1 + (n-1) \sum_{d=0}^n d - \sum_{d=0}^n d^2\\
 &= n(n+1) + (n-1) \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \\
 &= n^3\left( \frac12 - \frac26 \right) + \Theta\left(n^2\right)\\
 &= \frac16 n^3 + \Theta\left(n^2\right)
\end{split}
$$
which you could compute exactly if you wanted so. So the result is not just $O\left(n^3\right)$ (as is clear from the argument you present), but actually $\Theta\left(n^3\right)$.

Comment: (Couldn't edit the other comment, sorry) Hi, thanks for the quick response! Sorry for the long delay in getting back to you.

Unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with matrices, so I can't say I fully grasp the first direct approach.

What do you mean by this quote below? I don't really understand why we set $k = j - i +1$ (I suppose for simplification)? But from there, how do we bound the summation by $n - i +1$?

Comment: @quantitative_ (a) this does not use matrices directly, just a visualization (b) if $j$ goes from $i$ to $n$, then $j-i+1$ goes from $i-i+1 = 1$ to $n-i+1$

Comment: okay, thanks! So, since $j$ is bounded from $i$ to $n$, essentially since $i$ begins at $1$, then $j$ is always lower bounded by $1$ and then upper bounded by the range of $i$ to $n$ = $(n - i + 1)$?

Comment: @quantitative_ $j$ is always $\ge i$ and $\le n$, therefore $j-i$ is always $\ge 0$ and $\le n-i$. So if we let $k=j-i+1$ we get $1 \le k \le n-i+1$.

Comment: thank you! That makes sense. Basically since $$0 \leq j - i \leq n- i$$ and we add 1 to the lower bound and upper bound for the range of values for $j$? From there, I believe we use the common sum identity of $n(n+1)/2$, right? After that, why are we allowed to substitute in $m$ and then change the index?

Comment: @quantitative_ yes, correct, good

Comment: thanks! But why are we allowed to substitute in $m$ and then change the index?

Comment: @quantitative_ WE are not changing the index, it's a similar exercise in arithmetic. As $i$ goes $1 \to n$, you have $n-i$ going from $n-1$ down to $0$, thus $m = n-i+1$ goes from $n$ down to $1$. The order in which you sum does not affect the final result.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I get what you're saying. It's a similar concept to summing from 1 to n except in the reverse direction?

So, if $$n = 10$$ we see that the boundaries of $$n - i + 1$$ are at the extreme values for $$i = 1$$ and $$i = n?$$ i.e., $n - i + 1 = 10$ when $i = 0$ and $n - i + 1 = 1$ when $i = 10$? So in that way, we determine what $n - i + 1$ ranges from?

Comment: @quantitative_ yes :-) correct

Comment: thanks so much! That makes a lot more sense and is more intuitive than using the difference of the indices. Really appreciate your thorough explanations, was very helpful. :)

Comment: @quantitative_ glad to be of help